# Android : How to Navigate from one fragment to another , within a Tab?

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

The application has tow Tabs , Tab A and Tab B both extends Fragment . Now my question is , when I click on list item of Tab B , a new Fragment C should be called with in the tab . With the following code I am able to call Fragment C , but not within the tab .

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(getActivity(), C.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

When I am using activities , I can achieve solution to my problem  by using ActivityGroup . Is there any similar way in Fragments.

Answer (score 4):

try with this code onClick list item

```
private void stackAFragment() {
            Fragment f;
            f = new MedicationOrderFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.main_details_fragment_container, f);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried with your answer , but was not successful . When I am using activities , I can achieve solution to my problem  by using ActivityGroup . Is there any similar way in Fragments.

Comment: Actually, this is a very good way with fragment. But don't forget that you can only add new fragments within an activity (or fragmentActivity ...etc). You should take a look at this http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Answer (score 0):

try to replase your fragment:

```
protected void replaceDataFragment(Fragment fragment){
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ftr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ftr.replace(R.id.data<id of your fragment layout>, fragment);
        ftr.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ftr.commit();   
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried with your answer , but was not successful . When I am using activities , I can achieve solution to my problem  by using ActivityGroup . Is there any similar way in Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can just start a new activity using intents.
Try to use this in your fragment:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
R.id.my_container_in_xml, new MyFragment(), 0).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried with your answer , but was not successful . When I am using activities , I can achieve solution to my problem  by using ActivityGroup . Is there any similar way in Fragments.